Are London dispersion forces in xenon tetrafluoride strong enough to make it a solid?
Xenon_tetrafluoride ($\ce{XeF4}$) is a well-known square-planar molecule with no dipole moment. Molecules are thus have to be bound to each other by London dispersion forces (LDF) which are known to not be very strong (I think even for large molecules they aren't extremely strong).
I was surprised to see that under normal conditions $\ce{XeF4}$ is a crystalline solid. Does this mean that LDF are actually strong enough for $\ce{XeF4}$ to form a solid?

Quadrupole's gotta be big here.

Great point, but quadrupole is the next order correction after dipole so can it really be that strong?

At what temperature and pressure??

@DrMoishePippik It's just a solid, but sublimes relatively easily.

Be aware that a zero dipole moment of a molecule does not mean bonds are not polar. It just means that dipole moments of bonds mutually cancel each other. Like in $\ce{CO2}$ case.

I don't know whether quadrupole interactions are a big issue here. But there are plenty of examples of other solids where they can't contribute anything but where the simple dispersion forces are enough to make a solid form under normal conditions. Molecular iodine, for example.

If quadrupoles are important anywhere it's going to be here - nice big charge separation (v.old reference saying in XeF2 F is ~-0.7 ), nice long bonds (~2 Angstrom ), almost perfect geometry.

P.S.: Therefore it is rather Keesom_force than London force.

The quadrupolar interaction is of some importance here. The structure below, reported by The Materials Project, shows each molecule differently oriented from its neighbors; such a difference in orientation between neighboring molecules makes the quadrupole-quadrupole interaction attractive.

The fact that xenon tetrafluoride sublimes unless placed under higher than atmospheric pressure suggests that a liquid phase in which the molecules would not stay in this alignment is significantly less stable than this orientation-ordered solid. As for the strength of this interaction, xenon tetrafluoride is not going to be confused with magnesia or thoria, but it requires a higher temperature than strongly polar, hydrogen-bonded water to reach one atmosphere vapor pressure.

Solid carbon dioxide has basically the same molecular arrangement, also held together primarily by permanent quadrupole interactions.

And carbon dioxide, too, requires elevated pressure to access a liquid phase.
